# How can I create a json file from mysql database?

Tags: mysql, json, encoding

I want to create a json file.

```
$data = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id ASC;')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json_string = json_encode($data);
$file = 'data.json';
file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
```

My result:

```
[{
    "id": "123",
    "timestamp": "2017-05-12 16:22:39",
    "name": "bear",
    "description": "dance all day"
    },
  ....
}]
```

But the format I acutally would need is:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "123",
      "2017-05-12 16:22:39",
      "bear",
      "dance all day"
    ],
  ....
  ]
}
```

Comment: your result does not have a closing "]" ?

Comment: updated it for you

Comment: it depends on what you need. do you need an array of objects? or do you need an object with array data in it? your result is array of objects. the format you actually need is the latter. both valid json formats. http://json.org/

Comment: I need the exactly the second format to load it into a datatable.

Comment: then you will need to iterate your $people with a loop, then save each item one by one into the format you need. what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried `foreach($json_string as $value) { $new_array[] = $value; }` but I get only an error message: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156004/discussion-between-user1506104-and-jarla).

Comment: Before you get burned, use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` on `json_encode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$results= $db->query('SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id ASC;')->fetch_all();

$data = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $id = $row[0];
    $timestamp = $row[1];
    $name = $row[2];
    $description = $row[3];
    $data[] = array($id, $timestamp, $name, $description);
}
$json = json_encode(array("data" => $data));
```

Comment: you need a multi-dimensioinal array in json format right? hold on.

Comment: What do you think about JSON_PRETTY_PRINT

Comment: actually I need to remove the keys like "id", "timestamps" etc

Comment: oh ok i did not notice that. i updated. but still a one-dimentional array. more codes coming up. :p

Comment: please try this. let me know.

Comment: I tested it, the result is null, null,null, null,null, null,null, null,null, null,....

Comment: The problem is also, I need a solution, where I do not need to write $id, $timestamp etc. because these variables are always different

Comment: then please put more details in your question